# Is it possible to modify the next element (oldest element) in a c++ queue?

Tags: c++, struct, queue

Consider a queue of type packet

```
queue < packet > buffer;
```

where

```
struct packet         {
  int src_id;
  int dst_id;
  int inter_dst_id; 
  bool phase;
 };
```

Now, consider this:

```
if (buffer[i].Front().inter_dst_id == local_id && buffer[i].Front().phase == true)
    buffer[i].Front().phase = false;
```

But I can't write to 'phase' in the above case. Is it possible by any means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did the previous responses go? Something wrong?

Comment: the previous answer was wrong.

Comment: I'm confused over what `buffer[i]` is supposed to be doing. `std::queue<>` is a container adapter, and doesn't even expose `operator[](size_t)`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you need random access to the elements in a queue you shouldn't be using a `std::queue<>` adapter; you should just be using a `std::deque<>`. If all you want is to modify the element on the front of the queue, just use `front()`.

Comment: I am modelling a router with 4 ports. buffer[i] corresponds to i=0,1,2,3 for 4 different ports each containing some packets. I wish to change the 'phase' of the packet at the top of queue. I used deque. The error I am getting is this: `error: conversion from ‘packet’ to non-scalar type ‘std::deque<packet>::iterator {aka std::_Deque_iterator<packet, packet&, packet*>}’ requested`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@juanchopanza : I could not make the above thing work. Seems like you can not modify the front element of a queue. Instead, I used deque.

`deque <packet> buffer;`

then, I copied **buffer[i].front** to a temp variable. I changed the **phase** in the temp variable. Removed the **buffer[i].front** using `pop_front()`. Finally, pushed the temp variable with modified **phase** using `push_front()`.

I am new to stl and hence took some time. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to modify the next element (oldest element) in a c++ queue?

Yes, like this:

```
buffer.front().phase = false;
```

See more on [`std::queue` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

Comment: @VindRaider Yes it does.

Comment: :) , sorry, wrong choice of words. It did not work that way for me. The error in this case is: 
error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]

Comment: @VindRaider OK, it would be easier if you posted some (minimal) code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I could not make the above thing work. Instead, I used deque.
`deque <packet> buffer`
then, I copied _buffer[i].front_ to a temp variable. I changed the _phase_ in the temp variable. Removed the _buffer[i].front_ using `pop_front()`. Finally, pushed the temp variable with modified _phase_ using `push_back().